# Parallel bit operation based prime finder with openMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, primes, bitwise-operators

recently I have been studying C++. And the prime number finder is an exercise. After I wrote the serial version code, I tried to use openmp to parallelize the code. However, the serial version works fine but once I tried openmp version, the output (prime numbers between 1 and 100) is very wrong. Any suggestion?

Here is my code (the relative functions):

```
    void prime2_bits(const int& n)
    {
       omp_set_num_threads(4);
       int i,j,tp,sq=sqrt(n+1);
       int p[n/32+1];
       initint(p,n/32+1);
    #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(i,j,tp) schedule(dynamic)
       for(i=2;i<sq;i++){
         if(!((p[i/32]>>(i%32))&1)){ // see whether the ith bit is 0
           tp=i*i;
           for(j=tp;j<n+1;j+=i){
             p[j/32]|=(1<<(j%32)); // set the jth bit as 1
           }
         }
       }
    // Do the printing job
       for(i=2;i<n+1;i++)
         if(!((p[i/32]>>(i%32))&1)) cout<<i<<' ';
    }
```

and the output looks like:

```
using method 2 (bits to save space):
2 3 5 7 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 27 29 31 35 37 41 43 47 49 53 55 59 61 67 69 71 73 77 79 81 83 87 89 91 93 97 99 0 msec used!
```

Also, to increase efficiency, I modified the serial code again. Then tried to parallel it with openmp without success. Any suggestion for this?

the modified code:

```
void prime3_norev(const int& n)
{
   int i,j,tp,m=n+1;
   int pi=0;
   bool pFlag[m];
   int p[n/3];
   omp_set_num_threads(4);
   initbool(pFlag,m);
   initint(p,n/3);
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(i,j) schedule(dynamic) 
   for(i=2;i<m;i++){
     if(!pFlag[i]) p[pi++]=i;
     for(j=0;(j<pi)&&(i*p[j]<m);j++){
       pFlag[i*p[j]]=true;
       if(i%p[j]==0) break;
     }
   }
// Do the printing job
   for(i=0;i<pi;i++)
     cout<<p[i]<<' ';
}
```

and the corresponding output:

```
using method 3 (no revisits, space for time):
2 3 6 7 11 13 15 19 23 29 31 35 37 41 43 47 53 55 59 61 65 67 71 73 79 83 85 89 95 97 0 msec used!
```

The code was compiled with:

```
g++ -O2 -fopenmp fib.cc
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code you can use the ordered clause

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) ordered
for(int i=2;i<m;i++) {
    #pragma omp ordered
    if(!pFlag[i]) p[pi++]=i;
    //rest of code
```

For a working example see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa1eebf126940fb0.  I used schedule(static) there only to show the error easier without the ordered clause.

I'm not sure what effect ordered will have on performance though.  It looks to me like you're trying to parallelize the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  In that case I suggest you check out http://create.stephan-brumme.com/eratosthenes/.  It finds all the primes up to 10^9 in about 1 second using OpenMP.

Comment: The second linked article makes the same mistake that many others (including the author of this question) make: overlooks the fact that `schedule(dynamic)` defaults to chunk size of 1 and therefore introduces very high OpenMP overhead for simple loop bodies as each iteration is given to a different thread on a first-come-first-served basis.

Comment: @HristoIliev, that was only one step in that link and it was found to be only a small impovement.  His fastest function `eratosthenesBlockwise` uses static (implicitly).

Comment: @HristoIliev, I have never seen the ordered clause be useful for performance.  In all cases so far I have found a better algorithm which avoided ordered.  Have you ever found it to be useful?

Comment: Sure the small improvement comes from having 1 billion tasks queued. I'm seeing better speedups with larger chunks. Also ordered execution helps when the ordered block is just a small fraction of the loop body but in that particular case it can be replaced with `atomic capture`.

Comment: By "in that particular case" do you mean the OPs case?  I tired using atomic and critical but it did not work.

Comment: Yes, something like `#pragma omp atomic capture <new line> { pi0 = pi; pi++; } <new line> p[pi0] = i;`. The idea is to capture the value of `pi` before the increment and use it to index `p[]` while the increment is done atomically.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but my implementation of it (it's my first time using atomic capture) does not give the correct result http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/975fb1edc4d8d627

Comment: I'll give it a try when I find myself with more free time.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev I actually tried the method of the second link given by Z. It seems dynamic performs much better than static though I understand dynamic usually has much more overheading than static. Here is the restult: using sieving_odd_omp with 12 threads: dynamic with chunk size: 1! Wall time 1.69776 sec. || using sieving_odd_omp with 12 threads:static with chunk size: 1! Wall time 4.92371 sec.

Comment: @P_E_M_Lee, this is not a problem where iterations take the same amount of time, therefore static scheduling is not appropriate and the increase in run time is expected. But increasing the chunk size with dynamic scheduling should improve the performance (at least it did on my setup).